# iOS 13.4, Xcode 11.2 FCM not working in debug mode

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase-cloud-messaging, ios13, xcode11

Nowadays, after upgrading in ios 13.4, FCM(Firebase Cloud Message) was not receiving in my iphone.

In spite of the same code, in ios 12 it is working well.

But when I tested in TestFlight or Appstore version(perhaps it is release mode.), it is all working in in ios 13 either.

Why FCM is not working in ios 13.4, in debug mode?

Here is the fcm server send json.

```
{
   "to" : "[FCM PUSH TOKEN]",
   "content_available" : true,
   "mutable_content": true,
   "priority" : "high",
   "data":
   {
       "title": "title2",
       "message" : "content2",
   },
   "notification":
   {
       "title": "title1",
       "body" : "content1",
       "sound": "default"
   }
}
```

PS: In Firebase console, it is not working in debug mode, ios 13.4, either...

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: @Omtechguy After upgrading iOS version, it was fixed. I think that it was 14.3's bug.